# QGIS: How to shift point data to nearby grid cell with matching attributes?

Tags: vector, gis, qgis

I am dealing with data about tree species and habitats, both of which exist in vector format (point and polygon, respectively). Each point occurs within a specific grid cell of the polygon which has an attribute describing the primary land use of that grid cell.

[image: Sample data]

My goal is to create another dataset using the tree point data. Ideally this dataset will take into account the current habitat type (grid cell) and search within a specific distance for all cells matching that type. Finally, a new point will be randomly placed within one of the grid cells that match the original type.

Is this possible in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in QGIS. You've outlined three tasks.

1. *"Ideally this dataset will take into account the current habitat type (grid cell)."* You can use MMQGIS -> Combine -> Spatial Join to add data from the grid layer to the point layer.
2. *"And search within a specific distance for all cells matching that type."* You can use Toolbox -> Distance Matrix, with a variety of options to e.g., get all matching in a given distance, or k-nearest matching type.
3. *"A new point will be randomly placed within one of the grid cells that match the original type."* You can use Vector -> Research Tools -> Random Selection within Subsets to randomly select (sample) one or more grid cells for each type. Once you've randomly selected cells, you can Right Click -> View Table, for the grid layer, and then assign whatever value you want for selected cells, e.g. 1 for selected, 0 for not. You can then use this selection indicator variable for any additional spatial join or samplingyou might need. Or you can save sampled cells as a separte layer, Right Click -> Save Selection As. Once you have the sampled cells, you can generate one or more random points in each cell with Vector -> Research Tools -> Random Points Inside Polygons.

Comment: Hi @5ayat, thank you for your answer. I've been able to perform the spatial join, but the QGIS toolbox does not allow distance matrices to be constructed from two types of vector data (point v. polygon). I converted the grid layer to polygon centroids in order to use that function. I'll update with how that goes...